# MySQL -- List multiple SUMs in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, unpivot, lateral-join

I have a table that looks like:

| ID | Name | Color | Red_Count | Blue_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill | Red | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | John | Blue | 0 | 7 |
| 3 | Sam | Both | 5 | 2 |
| 4 | Tom | Both | 3 | 6 |

How do I query in MySQL to obtain the following result?

| Color | Total_Count |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 10 |
| Blue | 15 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with a lateral join (available starting MySQL 8.14):

```
select x.color, sum(cnt) total_cnt
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select 'Red', t.red_count
    union all select 'Blue', t.blue_count
) x (color, cnt)
group by x.color
```

The idea is that we only need to unpivot the two counts columns (the original `color` is superfluous), and then aggregate.

Doing this with a lateral join is more efficient, since it only scans the table once. In earlier versions, we would use `union all`:

```
select 'Red' color, sum(red_count) total_cnt from mytable
union all select 'Blue', sum(blue_count) from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/26rRmMQP)**